# Ethereum private-net - creating contract can't mine

Tags: dapp-development

I'm trying to get started on ethereum private-net. I'm using MIST and trying to do a basic "Hello World" contract on windows. I setup geth and got off setting a private-net and checked it's mining okay. When I add a contract through MIST, it shows processing and nothing happens.

[image: Attachment shows mist and the 3 transactions to deploy contract "Hello World"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testnet took awhile (10-15)minutes before it started reflecting in my wallet balance. I did mine to get enough eth test coins.